# moment.utc - warning on invalid input string format

Tags: momentjs

When testing my code that uses `moment.utc` I have some tests that use bad format: `moment.utc('13-06-2018T13:00:00')`. When doing this, I get this warning:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

Why is that? I guess `moment.utc` is shorthand that is using UTC format under the hood, and I don't see a method version that accepts format so I cannot get rid of this warning.

How can I parse valid/invald utc string with `moment.utc` so I don't get this warnings?

Answer (score 0):

As the warning and the linked [guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/), you have to take a look at [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs and use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for parsing strings not in ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 format.

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a live example:

```js
console.log( moment.utc('13-06-2018T13:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY[T]HH:mm:ss').format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```